# drf-spectacular not working when versioning is used (No operations defined in spec!)

Tags: django-rest-framework, versioning, drf-spectacular

Some weeks ago I installed `drf-spectacular`. Everything was working properly until I enabled **versioning in DRF** (Django Rest Framework).

I implemented `AcceptHeaderVersioning` and it was working correctly. But then I realized Swagger wasn't showing the endpoints at /docs/ and this message was shown: **"No operations defined in spec!"**.

If I comment `DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS` line in `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings, all endpoint are correctly shown in Swagger docs page (/docs/). However, it breaks my versioning: `request.version = None`.

I tested with `AcceptHeaderVersioning`, as well as with `URLPathVersioning` and `NamespaceVersioning`. Same result for all of them.

I read that `AcceptHeaderVersioning` was implemented a year ago. Link to the commit [here](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/commit/34d9c37c390eb32630bef4f3ad05121adcfa7e23#diff-d727722caf6fe5f5507940c9efbcbe843fcca1dec9ac64402f074b08dd1c294f).

But I also read that it was planned to change `modify_for_versioning` function and it could affect header versioning. Link to the function in plumbing module, [here](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/blob/master/drf_spectacular/plumbing.py#L857) and conversation [here](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/pull/144#pullrequestreview-479551663). In fact, a lot of changes have been made to the module the last year, check [here](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/commits/9b0c6545941d5fcb3fac6e541b4d0a88168b1977/drf_spectacular/plumbing.py).

These are my DRF settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Auth
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],

    # Swagger/docs
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',

    # Pagination
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 5,

    # Testing
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',

    # Versioning
    # https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#configuring-the-versioning-scheme
    'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS': 'rest_framework.versioning.AcceptHeaderVersioning',
    'DEFAULT_VERSION': None,
    'ALLOWED_VERSIONS': None,
    'VERSION_PARAM': 'version',
}
```

**Question**

1. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Any recommendation to make both work together (versioning and swagger)? Any suggestions?
2. And BTW (this is secondary and not the main question): Is it possible to launch `drf-spectacular` tests into my own project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1**: Versioning works just fine. This is a common mistake. When `SpectacularAPIView` is versioned with `AcceptHeaderVersioning` (via `DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS`), the request that fetches the schema from `SpectacularAPIView` likely does not contain the version header, and thus you only get unversioned endpoints (in your case none).

Either explicitly request a versioned schema with `/api/schema?version=v2` or set version manually with

```
path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(api_version='v2'), name='schema'),
```

[FAQ entry](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-an-empty-schema-or-endpoints-are-missing)

Where the [magic happens](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/blob/af1cccd613d115b50117bfc4479fdb87f0c30f4a/drf_spectacular/views.py#L72) and the order in which versions are used.

**Question 2**: The python wheels do not include the tests. For that you would need to install the source package: https://pypi.org/project/drf-spectacular/#files

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm!